# Refresh NFS mount

Tags: linux, nfs

If I check an NFS share on a machine and `ls` I get the folders.

If I got to the NFS host and add a new directory to `/etc/exports` for the client and do `exportfs -a` what do I run on the client to refresh the directories?

Example (pseudoish):

nfsNode01:

```
echo "/share clientNode01 >> /etc/exports";
exportfs -a;
```

clientNode01:

```
cd /share;
ls;
```

nfsNode01:

```
echo "/share/folder clientNode01 >> /etc/exports";  
exportfs -a;
```

clientNode01:

```
ls;
```

Results as still the same as above.

If I reboot the `/share/folder` shares are there. I know there has to be a way to refresh that info from NFS. I'm sure if I let the connection wait long enough the next time I mounted /dsl would do it. Can I just umount/mount or is there a better way?

Comment: mount or remount is in fact what's missing.  How would you expect the node to know about the newly created shares w/o you trying to mount them?

Answer (score 8):

If this is NFS4 on Linux, the following seems to do the trick:

> mount -o remount /share/

Answer (score 1):

Discover/view NFS shares from the client
**showmount -e**

Exports all file system paths specified in the /etc/exports file
**exportfs -r**

or you can restart the nfs server
**/etc/init.d/nfs restart**